# How can I insert data from csv to database? I'm getting multiple errors (python)

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

Here's my full code.

```
import cx_Oracle, pandas as pd

connstr="spark/pass@localhost:1521/orcl"
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
curs = conn.cursor()

csv = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Downloads/products.csv')
lst = csv.values.tolist()
t = tuple(lst)

#Here where I tried to insert values to DB
curs.executemany("INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", lst)
curs.commit()
curs.exit()

#Output
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I tried to execute in different ways, well, the idea was simple when I did my first insert form python, but didn't get it.

```
d = input("<value>: "), int(input('<value2>: '))
s = f"INSERT INTO <table-name>(column1, column2) VALUES {d}"
curs.execute(s)
conn.commit()
```

W1, here where I tried to to apply what I learnt

```
e = f"INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES {lst}"
curs.executemany(e)

#Output
TypeError: function missing required argument 'parameters' (pos 2)
```

W2

```
e = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
curs.executemany(e, lst)

#Output
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

W3

```
e = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
curs.executemany(e, csv)

#Output
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

W4,

```
curs.executemany("INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", lst)
#Output
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

W5

```
for r in csv: # Iterate through csv
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", *r)

#Output, also tried with (?, ?, ?, ?)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (7 given)
```

W6

```
curs.executemany("INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", t)

#Output
TypeError: parameters should be a list of sequences/dictionaries or an integer specifying the number of times to execute the statement
```

Comment: can you show us the output of t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why're you converting the list into a tuple? Can you directly pass the list to the `executemany` method:

```
curs.executemany("""INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(number, date, code, price) VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4)""", lst)
```

Also please note how I am referring to the params ( :1, :2 etc )

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Python driver doc has a complete example of loading from a CSV, see [Loading CSV Files into Oracle Database](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database):

```
import oracledb
import csv

# CSV file
FILE_NAME = 'data.csv'

# Adjust the number of rows to be inserted in each iteration
# to meet your memory and performance requirements
BATCH_SIZE = 10000

connection = oracledb.connect(user="hr", password=userpwd,
                              dsn="dbhost.example.com/orclpdb")

with connection.cursor() as cursor:

    # Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition.
    # This can improve performance by avoiding memory reallocations.
    # Here, one parameter is passed for each of the columns.
    # "None" is used for the ID column, since the size of NUMBER isn't
    # variable.  The "25" matches the maximum expected data size for the
    # NAME column
    cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)

    with open(FILE_NAME, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        sql = "insert into test (id, name) values (:1, :2)"
        data = []
        for line in csv_reader:
            data.append((line[0], line[1]))
            if len(data) % BATCH_SIZE == 0:
                cursor.executemany(sql, data)
                data = []
        if data:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
        connection.commit()
```